# XCODE : Changing which view controller BACK button segues to

Tags: xcode, ios7, segue, back

Is there a way to change the "parent" of a view controller so you can specify which view controller the back button will segue to without creating a custom back button?
Or is the only way to create a custom back button with a custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Try To create a custom button like

```
UIBarButtonItem * buttonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Back" ofType:@"png"]] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onBackClick:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[buttonBack] animated:YES];
```

and make a method..

```
- (IBAction)onBackClick:(id)sender
{
     // your code
     // Write your code what you want to do...
}
```

Comment: I implemented this but the normal back action still occurred.

Comment: "normal back action still occurred" - Means?

Comment: Meaning that it went back to the previous screen rather than the view controller I wanted it to go to. I put a peformseguewithidentifier action to the viewcontroller I wanted the back button to segue to in the onBackClick method, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the navigation controller, you could manually insert a view controller in to its stack of view controllers `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:]` before the current view controller. That would allow the navigation controller to perform its regular actions yet still navigate back to your desired view controller.